# Совместное использование scanf и fgets

Tags: c, scanf

Требовалось считать целое число, а затем строку. Написал такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int str_len; // Длина строки
    scanf("%i", &str_len);
    
    char* str;
    fgets(str, str_len, stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

После ввода строки >>4 red
получил ошибку:
timeout: the monitored command dumped core
./Playground/runner.sh: line 88:    12 Segmentation fault      timeout "$runtime" "$output" - < "/usercode/inputFile"
str_len, stdin);
В чем дело?

Comment: Как минимум указатель `*str` указывает в никуда, в итоге fgets записывает строку тоже в никуда и тем самым рушит программу

Comment: то есть решением будет выделить память char *str = malloc(str_len+1); и считать посимвольно с помощью getchar()?

Comment: Зачем посимвольно, тот же указатель и передать в fgets

Comment: Или `char str[str_len];` / Если вы уверены, что прочтете *разумное значение* str_len

Comment: Актуальный код **и вводимые данные** в студию

Comment: С этим разобрался.

Comment: Можете оформить свой комментарий, как ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строка `fgets(str, str_len, stdin);` получает на вход пустой указатель, а не указатель на буфер.
Должно быть так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int str_len; // Длина строки
    scanf("%i", &str_len);
    
    char* str = malloc(str_len);
    fgets(str, str_len, stdin);
    return 0;
}
```